# posix_spawn failure with jupyter notebook on mac (miniconda)

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, miniconda

I remember I had launched jupyter before installing miniconda.
For some reason, I keep getting error:

```
posix_spawn: 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.62.7
```

I don't have that version anymore, though.

I installed python 3.7, but after installing conda, things got a bit messy.

Here's my .bash_profile:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# added by Miniconda3 installer
export PATH="$HOME/Sites/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

`which python`:

```
/Users/me/Sites/miniconda3/bin/python
```

but:

```
jupyter notebook

python3.6: posix_spawn: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.62.7: No such file or directory
```

I tried to comment previous folder of python 3.7 in bash_profile, I think there is some old simlink somewhere preventing to find correct path - when I had python 3.6

I thought to look at a jupyter configuration to launch `jupyter notebook` command, but could not find it.

How could I fix it?

Please I don't want to use brew.

Comment: Try installing it again using conda itself: `conda install -c anaconda jupyter`.

Comment: yes, I noticed I can install it like that on my virtual environmnet in conda, but I'd like to fix the dependencies of jupyter command. I noticed in `~/Library/` folder I have two pythons 3.6 and 3.7 still. In my .bash_profile I have python 3.7. However, if I call jupyter, it will refer to the one in 3.6 folder. And I can't figure out why, since it is not mentioned on .bash_profile. To be clear - if I m in conda, Ok, I will install jupyter for every virtual env. But if not using Conda, I'd like to still using it - and should ref to the 3.7 folder, listed in .bash_profile.

Comment: List the available kernels using `jupyter kernelspec list`. Check if you find some discrepancy. Also, look at this [github issue](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/270) and try installing `ipykernel`.